# Is it possible to render a scene on a graphics card and then transfer the image back to system memory

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I'd like to know if it is possible to:

Take an image stored in system memory, for example cv::Mat.

Transfer it to the graphics card.

Do some processing on the graphics card using openGL / directX / 3D Engine 
(I'm aware OpenCV has functionality for some of it's algorithms but this is not what I'm looking for). For example rendering a mesh.

Then transfer the data back to a cv::Mat.

I'd like to know a good platform independent way of doing this

Comment: have a look at: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object and maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Comment: @Micka: Neither of those is required for the GPU→CPU memory space transfer.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenGL there are 2 essential functions:

> Take an image stored in system memory, for example cv::Mat.
>
> Transfer it to the graphics card.

glTexImage…

> Then transfer the data back to a cv::Mat.

glReadPixels

all the rest like FBOs, PBOs and such is just for making things more efficient or to allow for reading back from certain resources, that don't have a direct way to access them.